# How to align seamless textures?

Tags: texturing

I'm doing a pathway which involves a curve/corner, i can't seem to be able to texture it properly, I want it to be seamless...i just cant do it...the texture I,m using is seamless,
Things that I've tried:

1.Make single object(One straight path tile and one corner)

Result: Textures wouldn't align

2.Make it so that i would get a corner with 2 straights at the end(as shown in the pic)

3.With the model I have in the pic, I straighten the UV of the curve but it still doesn't align

I was expecting an easier way to do this or a fix...Thank you

The first and second pic is with the UV straighten and the result
[image]
[image]

Third and fourth shows the normal UV and Straighten
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to have a special corner texture that will seamlessly tile into the straight pieces.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid seams you need to unwrap your path as a single UV island. This UV island will be straightened out, be all quads and lie horizontally in the UV space. The bottom left hand corner of the UV island will be snapped to the UV space X = 0.00 and Y = 0.00. Then the UV island will be scaled along the X axis until the texture looks about correct on the object in the 3D viewport.

**1:** To Unwrap so that the path's UV's will be all quads in face select mode select a face of the path that is already a quad that has  angles of 90° at each corner.

**2:** Then select the rest of the path that will be using the path texture.

**3:** Open the UV Unwrap menu and choose the option **Follow Active Quads**

**4:** In the last operator panel choose either the **Length Average** or **Length** option.

**5:** The Uv's should unwrap with all UV faces as quads.
[image]

**6:** In the **UV editor** select the UV island and (if necessary)rotate it so that it is lying horizontally in the UV space.

**7:** From the UV menu enable the **Constrain to Image Bounds** option.

**8:** Drag the UV island down so that the lower left hand corner of the UV island is "snapped" at the lower left hand corner of the UV space.
[image]

**9:** Check that the 2d cursor is also positioned at X =0.00 and Y = 0.00 in the UV space.

**10:** Change the **Pivot Point** to **2d Cursor**. This will be used as the origin for the scaling in the next step.

**11:** Select the UV island and scale it up along the **Y axis** until the top edge of the UV's align with the top edge of the UV space.

**12:** **Uncheck the Constrains to Image bounds** option in the **UV menu**.

13: Scale the UV's along the **X axis** so that they extend beyond the UV space until the texture on the object in the 3d viewport looks OK.
[image]

If you notice that the texture looks a bit deformed (wavy) where the path bends then adding more longitudinal loop cuts along the length of the path will lixiviate a lot of this deforming.

Answer (score 0):

Your UV-Map is stretched. Your last approche is pritty close. Maybe unwrapping it in `Top View` with `Project vom View` will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press 7 to have a view of your model from top and make a UV mapping*from view* (select the faces you need and press U - ***Project from view***)